# MySQL strange behavior when comparing comma-separated string with number

Tags: mysql, sql, string, numbers, comparison

I am experiencing some weird behavior with MySQL. Basically I have a table like this:

```
ID     string
1      14 
2      10,14,25
```

Why does this query pull id 2?

```
SELECT * FROM exampletable where string = 10
```

Surely it should be looking for an exact match, because this only pulls id 1:

```
SELECT * FROM exampletable where string = 14
```

I am aware of `FIND_IN_SET`, I just find it odd that the first query even pulls anything. Its behaving like this query:

```
SELECT * FROM exampletable where string LIKE '10%'
```

Comment: comma-separated columns are pure evil. don't use them.

Comment: See also [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you compare a numeric and a string value, MySQL will attempt to convert the string to number and match. ***Number like strings are also parsed***. This we have:

```
SELECT '10,14,25'      =   1     -- 0
SELECT '10,14,25'      =  10     -- 1
SELECT 'FOOBAR'        =   1     -- 0
SELECT 'FOOBAR'        =   0     -- 1
SELECT '123.456'       = 123     -- 0
SELECT '123.456FOOBAR' = 123.456 -- 1
```

The behavior is [documented here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html) (in your example it is the last rule):

> ...
>
> If one of the arguments is a decimal value, comparison depends on the
>   other argument. The arguments are compared as decimal values if the
>   other argument is a decimal or integer value, or as floating-point
>   values if the other argument is a floating-point value.
>
> In all other cases, the arguments are compared as floating-point
>   (real) numbers.

Comment: It's worse even than this, because a conversion like this also breaks any index that might have existed on the `string` column, meaning the database has to attempt this conversion and compare on _every row in the table_.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn as a programmer you must make sure that you are comparing apples to apples.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you. it converted 10,14,25 into 10 to be able to compare it. The closest documentation i have found if anyone is interested is:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html